# Call to undefined method : laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have simple blog crud app, I have added tags to my pages, am  using [select js](https://select2.org/) for selecting and editing tags in input,

Now I want when a user clicks edit certain page the input should contain tags related to that page.

I mean something like this below

[image]

Now when a user clicks to edit a certain page the input is empty

Here is my solution

edit.blade (just tag input with custom js)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" name="tags[]" multiple="multiple">

        @foreach ($tags as $tag)

        <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{$tag->name}}</option>

        @endforeach
 </select>
@section('script')

{!! Html::script('js/select2.js') !!}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2().val({!! json_encode($pages->tags()->getRelatedIds()) !!}).trigger('change');

</script>
@endsection
```

Here is my page list controller (just function for editing)

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $pages = PageList::find($id);
        $tags =PageListTag::all();

        return view('pages.edit', ['pages' => $pages, 'tags' => $tags]);
    }
```

Here in my Tag controller

```
class TagController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $tags = Tag::all();
        $pages = PageList::all();
        return view('pages.index', compact('tags', 'pages'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($reguest, array('name'=>'required|max:255'));
        $tag = new Tag;
        $tag->name = $request->name;
        $tag->save();
        $request->session()->flash('succes', 'Tag was successful created!');
        return redirect()->route('pages.index');
    }
}
```

Here is my page list model

```
class PageList extends Model
{  
    protected $fillable = [
        'pagetitle',
        'articlelist',
        'status',
        'prebid',      
    ];

    public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\PageListTag');
    }
}
```

Here is my PageListTag model

```
class PageListTag extends Model
{
    public function pagelist()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\PageList');
    }
}
```

Now when I run my app I have the following error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::getRelatedIds() (View: C:\custom-xammp\htdocs\royalad-dashboard\resources\views\pages\edit.blade.php)
```

What am I doing wrong in my codes?

Comment: I don't see `getRelatedIds` defined anywhere.

Comment: The `getRelatedIds` method doesn't exists

Comment: @IlGala so what is alternative to that????

Comment: Try use `$pages->tags()->pluck('tags.id')` or `$pages->tags()->pluck('id')`` instead of `$pages->tags()->getRelatedIds()`

Comment: You simply have to get the ids... `$pages->tags()->get()->pluck('id')`. Have a look at the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck)

Comment: Your right , now works, but when I click save I get the following error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::sync()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to build many-to-many relationship between tables.
But many-to-many relationships requires third table called Pivot table.

If, however you wanted to achieve one-to-many, you should do like this:

PageList model:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\PageListTag');
```

PageListTag model:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\PageList');
```